# How to pull data from an API and make it into an embed

Tags: discord.js

I'm somewhat very new to JavaScript and Discord.JS , I have a question. I'm wanting to make a mars weather command for my bot, however, I'm unsure how to do this with an embed, etc with my command handler and everything.
I'm currently pulling the API from [MarsAPI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mars-insight-weather-node)

It would be helpful to figure out how to do this currently, I have defined Temperature, Wind Speed, and Pressure in a json file to pull that without having to crowd the current file for my command.

Comment: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview. You can follow this guide to learn how to make embeds. You'll probably have to play around with the fields until you're satisfied with how it looks.

Comment: I'm aware how to create an embed, which isn't what I'm asking. I'm asking how to convert, an API which is for a website, and have the response of it as a command for a Discord bot, like displaying the info it would do for a website.

Answer (score 1):

The Mars API is a RESTful API. That means you can make requests and create, update, read, or delete data over an HTTP connection. They're very popular and relatively easy to use once you get the basics down.

To make things easier, various packages available on NPM can help you utilize REST APIs efficiently over HTTP (or any other data you can fetch online). In this post, I will use the [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) package. It goes like this:

```js
const axios = require('axios');

// for example, this endpoint could fetch a random image everytime this endpoint is hit
axios.get('http://my-api.lol/v1/a-random-meme').then(data => data.json()).then(body => {
    message.channel.send({ embed: {
      color: 'GREEN',
      image: {
        url: body.image // could look something like: https://img.my-api.lol/cat-meme-23.gif
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Now, this is a pretty barebones example, but I think it helps get the point across—something to keep in mind. As you see, I used `body.image` to represent the image URL. This object property is going to be different based on the API and what type of data you're trying to access. How do you get around this? Simply check if the API you're using has documentation you can look or do `console.log(body)` to see more information.

I have a source I'd like to recommend. It's a guide made by the Discord.js community. Check it out in full! This particular page I'm linking you [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/rest-api.html#making-http-requests-with-node) gives you more information about using a REST API with Discord.js.

Comment: Thanks :) I was using that guide, but they hardly give any info about transitioning it into a embed, as I've used superagent before, but can't seem to get around pulling data from an actual API with a HTTPS request as like this. Would I need to add all of that to a different file? Or anything I need to do?